# Switch to the finish page in Inno Setup installation

Tags: installation, windows-installer, inno-setup

I added a few custom pages to my setup. In one of this custom pages I do some checks. If this checks failed, I want switch to finish page. *How can I do this?*

**I can not do this with *ShouldSkipPage* event function because:**

```
function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // this will NEVER happened - see documentation below
  if (PageID = wpInstalling) or (PageID = wpPreparing) or (PageID = wpWelcome) then
  begin
    // skip install - simply for example
    result := True;
    exit;
  end;

  resutl := false;
end;
```

**From Inno Setup documentation:**

> The wizard calls this event function
>   to determine whether or not a
>   particular page (specified by PageID)
>   should be shown at all. If you return
>   True, the page will be skipped; if you
>   return False, the page may be shown.
>
> Note: This event function **isn't called**
>    **for the** wpWelcome, wpPreparing, and
>   wpInstalling pages, nor for pages that
>   Setup has already determined should be
>   skipped (for example,
>   wpSelectComponents in an install
>   containing no components).

Comment: The question is too vague. I tried, and `ShouldSkipPage` worked for me. Add some minimal sample code to your question that demonstrates the problem you're having.

Comment: @mghie I add some code to my question

Comment: Load the `Example1.iss` file. Add a `ShouldSkipPage` function that says `Result := PageID <> wpFinished;` Run the setup, and you will only see the Welcome and the Finished pages. That's a good thing, both should always be there, else it would be surprising for the user. He at least needs to be able to cancel on the first page, and he needs to know that the setup has finished.

Comment: I see not only finish page, but Welcom and Installing process to...

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry, i did not understand why you cannot use ShouldSkipPage.
The usual way of doing it **is** in ShouldSkipPage:

```
function ShouldSkipPage(curPageId : Integer) : Boolean;
begin
  {For a certain condition, skip to wpFinished}
  if (SomeCondition and (curPageId <> wpFinished)) then
    Result := True
  {Probably more checks}
  else
    Result := False
end;
```

Comment: +1, good answer. @Sasha - try it, it does work. But you may need to add checks to skip your normal installation steps too if you need to bail out.

Comment: DO NOT WORK. See my question!

Comment: @Sasha: That's not encouraging people to help you.

Comment: This only automates the Next, Next, Next, doing the install as it goes. If they want to skip the install itself, they need to cancel.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you are performing a check, and if it fails, you want to skip wpWelcome, wpPreparing, and wpInstalling (and perhaps more custom pages).

I assume that you also want to skip the actions performed when these pages are shown, specifically, you don't want to perform the installation step.

If that is the case, you should **cancel** the installation, not continue it without performing the actual installation steps. You can do it in `InitializeSetup`, for example:

```
Procedure InitializeSetup();
VAR
  Check: Integer;
BEGIN
  // perform you check here, set the variable according to it's result

  IF (Check <> 0) THEN
    // abort installation
    Return False;
  ELSE
    Return True;
END;
```

---

**Edit**
In response to your comment: The easiest solution would be to show a message box with the result of your check, instead of a complete wizard page. If that is not enough for your purposes I would suggest the following approach:

1. Perform your check in `InitializeSetup` and store the result in a global variable.
2. Create a new wizard page (lets call it *CheckResult*) to display the results of your check, it should be displayed directly after `wpWelcome`.
3. In that page's `OnNextButtonClick` just call `CancelButtonClick`, that way the installation is always aborted when this page is displayed
4. Now is the time to modify `ShouldSkipPage` ;-) If the global check variable indicates that everything is ok, skip your *CheckResult* page, so that the installation is not aborted automatically

This *should* work, but if you somehow can, follow the KISS principle and go with the message box approach.

Comment: Before exit from installation I want to show a user the page with result of my check.